# rails 4.1 - rendering nested partial in JS template - local variable issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

in my controller **create** action i have:

```
if @content.save
respond_to do |format|
 @contents = Content.all
 format.html ...
 format.js
end
```

in my view I have:

```
some html ...
render partial("home/contents")
```

contents partial:

```
@contents.each do |c| 
    some html ... (image being rendered by amazon s3/cdn)
      <%= render 'action_buttons', :c => c  %>
    end
```

action_buttons partial:
2 submit buttons (one for create, one for delete)

This works fine when the page is loaded - however when I submit the create action in the action buttons partial, the js error: undefined local variable or method 'c'.

In my create.js.erb I have

```
$(".action_buttons").html("<%= j render("home/action_buttons"), :c => c %>")
```

so it looks like its trying to render the view correctly so the syntax is correct however the c variable is not rendering

Keep in mind that I am only doing this because if render out the contents partial, it will re-render the image in that partial that is being served by s3, so the entire page has multiple images. To avoid this I would rather render on just the action buttons.

Comment: ok so I should just pure jquery/ajax instead of rails build in js templates for something like this?

Comment: Just realized you are passing a single content to your partial. I think a better approach would be to target your single content which is being saved and render partial only for that

Comment: which is what I did originally did but the single content object includes an image which is stored on amazon s3 so if i do that, the image has to be re-rendered for each content on the page - so i'm really just trying to re-render part of the partial I guess by creating a partial inside that partial (if that makes sense) - Would be nice to use rails templates but might have to go back to doing this manually in AJAX

Comment: Why do you want to update action for each of your contents? Your ultimate goal is to append newly created content right?

Comment: on the page there is say 50 contents (each artist has multiple contents) - 1 div for each content. in one content, there is an image and 2 submit buttons (remote-delete and create - each with an image based on state - either following or not following). The create action will re-render the buttons so display the text "follow  (which triggers create.js.erb) or unfollow (triggers destroy.js.erb)". So say an artist has multiple content on one page the follow button should read "following" on each of the divs of that artist's content.

Comment: I should add taht this works in my view - only not in the js.erb

Comment: ok so you just want to change the content of buttons? I mean follow should change to following?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your contents partial to this

```
<div id="contents">
  @contents.each do |c| 
    <%= render partial: "content", locals: {c: c}
  end
</div>
```

Your content partial would be like this:

```
some html ... (image being rendered by amazon s3/cdn)
<%= render 'action_buttons', :c => c  %>
```

Now in your create.js.erb file you will have this code:

```
$("#contents").append("<%=j render partial: 'content', locals: {c: @content} %>");
```

**Update:**

You can't update just actions as it's inside a loop so you have two options either to render your whole partial again or use js to target your buttons and change there content but since you don't want to render your whole partial so you are left with second option. To update links content your create.js.erb would be like this:

```
$("#contents").append("<%=j render partial: 'content', locals: {c: @content} %>");
$(".follow").text('following'); // give class to all of your follow buttons and then change there content to following
```